# Is aggregation of GPL and non-GPL software possible?

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, distribution

A colleague of mine is working with Matlab on a simulation of some sort. In order to enhance the simulation she needs a way of adding some additional data that can be easily generated using a GPL C++ library called [OpenFOAM](https://www.openfoam.com/). What is the best way to preserve the closed source nature of the Matlab portion of the project, while also benefitting from the GPL library?

I gave her the following advice after doing some research but additional feedback is more than welcome:

The simulation only uses the output data (e.g. a CSV file of some sort) so in my opinion she does not need to link her Matlab application to the GPL library (although it would definitely be more convenient even though it would require - beside the licensing issue - writing a wrapper for the library in Matlab). Instead she can create a simple command line tool that can be

- executed by Matlab itself as an external command (e.g. `system('gpl-tool.exe');`)
- open sourced completely, since it's linking against the GPL library and is distributed in a binary form alongside the Matlab application

Effectively this would create two separate applications with the closed-source one depending on input from the open-source one. Each application can also function on its own.

I have read that in some cases it may be problematic, e.g. when a developer adds a bogus client-server architecture to their application so that they can separate the open from the closed source part of their application. In the case of my colleague the two "components" can be run fully independently from one another with the only link between the two being e.g. that CSV file. However, currently, we are talking about creating two separate applications and not adding client-server communication.

I would be interested though if such a client-server communication is acceptable in this situation since I am also planning in converting her simulation into a web service for a cloud platform I am working on and that we will be hosting.

Comment: Whether what you describe counts as aggregation or not is hard to answer. See also the GPL faq on this, where they give their own position about this: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation

Comment: I've read the GPL FAQ. That's why I am asking here since I'm interested in this case in particular. In the end it's all "lawyers will decide" but I would very much like us not to land in such a situation. :D

Comment: Is it necessary to distribute the OpenFOAM part itself together with the closed source portion?  How about using OpenFOAM to generate the simulation data offline, and then shipping only that simulation data together with the app? The app will use the data bundled with the closed source app.

Comment: I will not distribute OpenFOAM with the closed source application at all. It's about having two separate applications, one using OpenFOAM and being fully open source. I need to check how OpenFOAM works exactly, but hopefully data can be exchanged between the two applications via a file. This is also the case I am describing in my post.

Comment: Rather than OpenFOAM itself I was thinking about "the OpenFOAM-derived portion". I.e. if you take OpenFOAM (a GPL app) and then customize it, naming your version "blahblah.exe" which is going to be called by your closed-source APP, then of course blahblah.exe is derived from GPL software and therefore must itself be GPL. But I'm asking, do you really need to distribute blahblah.exe at all? Could you use blahblah.exe on your own machine to generate the simulation data, and then distribute only the closed source app, along with the simulation data?

Comment: Does Matlab have to generate the CSV ? If **NOT** : She can make the workflow such that Matlab uses what-ever CSV is given & She can distribute Sample CSV Data along with the Simulation tool. She can give Instructions on "generating" the newer CSV Data via various tools including that GNU tool. If **YES** : She can provide a "generic" tool which "makes" Dummy Data , with Instructions on installing better replacement tools including the GNU tool. She is not packaging those two tools together. Users are free to Install Matlab & GNU tools & other tools.

Comment: Did you think about using GNU Octave for this project instead of Matlab? It is largely compatible and is open source on GPL.

Comment: @Maniues Sadly, we are using a lot of proprietary toolboxes that, at least  to my knowledge, there is not out-of-the-box and/or feature set solution for in Octave.

Comment: @Brandin The EXE is for distribution. There is not way around that.

Comment: @Prem That is a very good idea, though it would require considerable extra effort and knowhow from the customer. Quite often the end user needs just something to click and look at rather than understand the essence of fluid dynamics. :D